# How to build RESTful web service API for user login using C# to consume on my iPhone app

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am going to build RESTful web service using C# (maybe ASP.Net MVC) to consume on my iPhone app.
I have been surfing few days, and I found this could be good start point.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233572/Build-truly-RESTful-API-and-website-using-same-ASP

But I have noticed there are only for customers and orders related APIs.
The APIs what I want to build are "user login" and "register user" features.

There is "User login" feature on the view, but it is only for ASP.NET membership provider related, not RESTful web service API.

How can I build this web service API for login, register user?

Any advice?

Comment: Side note: have you considered using existing authentication provides (like Facebook)? Building authentication system properly is not trivial task and not necessary user friendly (not everyone wants to register for just one more service)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of being able to login in the traditional sense is a stateful behavior. REST philosophy IMHO is leaning more into being stateless.

Some approaches that you may want to consider are 1) HTTP Basic Authentication, 2) OAuth, 3) OAuth2.

In the case of HTTP Basic Authentication for example, the username and password are combined in a hash and is packaged into the HTTP request as an authorization header. For every request that arrives the server can look into the request header and validate the username and password. Because the credentials are submitted for each and every request the server have no need to maintain state.

If you really need to maintain a login state it is probably better to implement it on the client side.